# Find a minimum distance with a number of even green edges

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

Hi I'm a computer science student, in my second year. During my studies, I got stuck with a question I couldn't solve, a question I was exposed to in order to expand my knowledge.
Question: There is an undirect graph, with edges of positive weight, I have to find I am the minimum distance between, in addition The graph has 2 types of edges - blue and green. I need to find a minimum distance between and also the number of its green edges in the tree is even.

[image]

I was thinking of an algorithm based on the Dijkstra algorithm.
Let's start from s
Each time we go to the bow with the minimum number.
If we have to go to a green vertex - right after that we try to go - to another green vertex.

[image]

I tried to draw my idea but it didn't work properly.

Why doesn't my idea work properly? what am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just implement Djikstra without carring about green/red edges. When you get the shortest path, check if it contains an even number of green edges. If so, you got your path. Else, (optionally) remove that path from the list and continue searching for the shortest path

Comment: Thanks for the response, why am I supposed to build Dykstra, no reference to the color type? Another thing, with this question you cannot edit the graph - you cannot delete a certain arc

Comment: Because if you take care about the colors while seeking the shortest path, you might not getting the shortest. And for your second question, in Dijkstra you don't edit the graph, but store the list of paths, sorted by total weight (the first of the list being the one with the less weight)

Comment: find a minimum distance between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would construct a new graph.

For each vertex i in the original graph, construct two vertices in the new graph numbered 2i and 2i+1.

For each blue edge i to j, construct edges 2i to 2j and 2i+1 to 2j+1.
For each green edge i to j, construct edges 2i to 2j+1 and 2i+1 to 2j.

Then Dijkstra's algorithm on the new graph from 2i to 2j will tell you the shortest distance from vertex i to j with an even number of green edges.  (2i to 2j+1 will tell the shortest distance with an odd number of green edges.)

The idea is that we switch from the even graph to the odd graph whenever we traverse a green edge.

Your idea sounds like it only considers paths with two consecutive green edges.  This will probably work for some graphs, but not all as in some case the optimum route may not include consecutive green edges.

UPDATE

For the graph in your comment:

[image]

the new graph looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me tremendously, I tried to draw, the graph. I got a little weird graph, am I missing something?
 - From this graph I tried to draw.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOfNP.png
- This is what I got
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZIJH.png

Comment: Something small, I'd love if you could answer me briefly.
If I start from vertex # 2 - will I get an even number of greens?

Comment: Starting from vertex 2, you will have an even number of greens to reach any even vertex in the new graph.  For example, suppose you wanted a route from 1 to 3 in the original graph with an even number of greens.  In this case you would search for a route from 2 to 6 in the new graph.